# Invoke SQL file which invokes multiple SQL files

Tags: oracle, batch-file

Environment:

Database oracle 11g
Windows 2008 R2

I have a batch program which creates an SQL file (ORACLE) which invokes other SQL files

For example the generated SQL file by batch script is called `Generatedfile.sql`

```
spool <somelogdir/logfile.log>
prompt execute abc.sql
@ <\path\to\abc.sql\>abc.sql

prompt execute XYZ.sql
@ <\path\ to\ XYZ.sql\>XYZ.sql

etc.

spool off
exit;
```

I am invoking the SQL file using

```
sqlplus -S <someUsername>/password@hostname:1521/Some_SID @Generatedfile.sql
```

SQL file just sits and spins without doing anything. Spool generated is empty.

Comment: Try it with the "-S" flag to see what it is/not doing.  Also have you tried manually running any of the called scripts to check they work?

Answer (score 0):

I *assume* that the statement in `\path\to\abc.sql` is not terminated by a `;` or a `/`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, of course. Edited in answer.